# Download the magento connect extensions list

Tags: extensions, search, magento-connect

I'm currently building a magento connect extensions search: http://magentoconnect.algolia.com/ but I have a hard time downloading the extensions list + associated metadata. I found http://connect.magentocommerce.com/community/Chiara_PEAR_Server_REST/p/packages.xml but then I cannot find a way to have relevant meta-data per extension.

Any chance someone know where I could find those information? Even crawling the page doesn't provide me all the metadata (like the tags/categories associated to an extension).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Might I ask why you're building a second `connect` site? Specially if you're using the data from the real connect there is no added benefit. And who will moderate this site etc?

Comment: @SanderMangel Because of scenarios like -> my other query https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193481/unable-to-find-all-magento-1-extension-screenshots-reviews-in-magento-2-marke

This question doesn't answer how to retrieve the screenshots from any archive and hence my other query and the need for a new connect site maintained by the community.

Comment: @redox: The link to the algolia search is down. Were you able to build the magento connect extensions search? Because the magento connect is  discontinued since September 15th without any advance notice of 18 months as promised to the community by Jason Wooley, Sr VP Magento Product Strategy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to find \*all\* Magento 1 extension screenshots, reviews in Magento 2 Marketplace. Any alternative archive to search/discover/save?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193481/unable-to-find-all-magento-1-extension-screenshots-reviews-in-magento-2-marke)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this link to fetch all of them:

http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/packages.xml

However, it still won't be too reliable as it contains also extensions which are no longer available on Magento Connect site.

You can also fetch list of releases for single extension eg:

http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/m2epro_ebay_magento/releases.xml

And then extension release details:

http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/m2epro_ebay_magento/3.0.0/package.xml

There are some descriptions and other data there, however it doesn't include url or image.

FYI, all this details come from `Mage_Connect_Rest` class which exist in each Magento release.

Comment: Ah yes, interesting link. Do you know if there is a way to fetch the info for every single extension (image, description, title, etc...)?

Comment: Yes, I've just updated answer.

Comment: Nice! This was what i was lloking for atm. Is there any documentation about this? Maybe further XMLs?

Comment: @sv3n I have never found documentation for this

Comment: And after I can download what I need this way (as seen in example above)
`http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/m2epro_ebay_magento/3.0.0/m2epro_ebay_magento-3.0.0.tgz`