# How to keep extensions from Magento Connect up2date without connect-manager?

Tags: magento-1, extensions, magento-connect, third-party-module

This is not a question about solving a technical problem, it's about getting some input how to realize my idea in the "best" way. ;)

**Current situation:**

I support a shop that uses a lot of extensions. Most of them are maintained at Github, so they can easily updated via modman/composer ... BUT ... there are some, that are only updated at *Magento Connect*.

What i have done till now - and it's really annoying - was a periodic check at magento connect, download latest version, hosted or update them on Github (or Bitbucket private repo for payed once) and deployed them via modman/composer.

**Aims:**

I don't need a out-of-the-box upgrade process, it would be more then enough when a get notification about new version without visiting magento connect manually and without using Magento connect manager.

**Plan:**

Build a simple as possible extensions that notifies me about new releases at **Magento Connect.**

**Idea:**

- gather installed extension from Magentos merged XML
- store them in a DB-Table (name, version, ...)
- add a field to (manually) store *Magento Connect*-URL once
- add a cronjob that looks for newer releases *(1)*
- add a admin notification message, if an update is available

**Note (1): long time planned - w/o no idea to realize - but today i found a possibility howto grab all required info. See: [Download the magento connect extensions list](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73109/download-the-magento-connect-extensions-list)**

I still have to download lates release, update my Git/BB-Repo and deploy it, but it would save a lot of time to periodically check **Magento Connect**.

**Question:**

**I assume this idea is interessting for all that rely on Magento connect-extensions and don't want to use Magento connect manager ... as long it's not necessary.**

> Before i start coding, I just want to ask you for *smarter* ideas!

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: This question doesn't answer how to retrieve the screenshots from any archive and hence my other query is still unresolved with full certainty and not a duplicate. Please check the complete query. Thank you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193481/unable-to-find-all-magento-1-extension-in-magento-2-marketplace-any-alternative

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download the magento connect extensions list](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73109/download-the-magento-connect-extensions-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension is not complete yet, but it does what I need at the moment.

[image]

Some things can be changed, but it works for now ... to do's

- accept extension key AND full connect url
- cronjob missing
- add system config
- add admin notification
- support for GIT repos (?)
- ...

---

#### Edit:

Because of [Magento Connect to close on September 15](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190158/magento-connect-to-close-on-september-15) added [dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sreichel/magento-Sr_VersionCheck/master/src/app/code/community/Sr/VersionCheck/data/sr_version_check_setup/data-install-0.0.2.php) for all extension that are still downloadable ...

[image]

<sup>Download: https://github.com/sreichel/magento-Sr_VersionCheck</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Your overview specs for this concept sound interesting and it would be good to know the final result of your extension :)

My thoughts on a starting point for you below...

I'm not sure if you are using Magento 1 or 2.

I would suggest looking into the implementation of the n98-magerun plugin/module Hypernode. With Hypernode there is a command to check for updated versions to extensions:

```
  n98-magerun hypernode:modules:list-updates
```

The GitHub repository for this module:
https://github.com/Hypernode/hypernode-magerun/

A quick solution to your issue would be to run the hypernode command as a cron and have it email you the results periodically but I sense you want a more comprehensive solution.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of hypernode and it may be a really good working solution (community-driven, frequently updated), but i'm in favor to see further good ideas :) I use N98 excessively, but maybe we can find a more "magento-connect-tailored"/comprehensive  solution. (Btw it's for M1)

Comment: Hey ... upvoting a suggestion/answer w/o upvoting the idea is bit unfair ... :P  I already played around a bit and first "release" should be available during next two weeks. (Sorry for holidays ...and these kind of spam :P)

Comment: @sv3n Seen this now, upvoted! Sorry about the delay :) Look forward to the first release. Are you planning to handle custom modules not present on Magento connect? e.g. http://packages.firegento.com/

Comment: ATM, it is not planned. I've an (ugly) extension on my Github account, that checks modman installed modules, but it depends on git installed at the server and some shell commands ... so it will not work for everybody. I keep this in mind and maybe i'll add it later.