# Magento Connect to close on September 15

Tags: magento-1, magento-connect

As the title says Magento team will close the old Magento Connect. For me, it is a bad idea, this place provided for years a strong resource of solutions and inspiration. There are lots of people around the world using Magento CE 1 who need these extensions. Checking the new marketplace it is looking great, but there are thousands of extensions their developers did not migrate them to the new platform.

I would like to know how this will affect those who are installing extensions using Magento Downloader. Will this feature work after closing or not?

Is there a way to backup all extensions in community folder from Magento Connect?

Comment: This is a harsh way to push people towards using the new marketplace. I don't feel the new design matches the sorting and ease of the current system. Why close this over a year before End of Life for M1? Some Devs are really going to suffer from this.

Comment: If all will send emails to Magento Marketplace we hope they will understand our needs. Really closing the old Magento Connect website before Magento 1 EOL it is like a punch in our faces, no matter we are just users or developers. Just check how many extensions are in the new marketplace, most of them are paid. If Magento team can allow me to get all extensions from MC with all information they can burnt it then (joking).  I prefer them taking a look into the Bugtracker better than cutting things which help.

Comment: i have mailed them asking to extend the date till the end day of M1, next year. You could also do the same here: marketplace@magento.com

Comment: Please note there is no end date for Magento 1. A couple of months ago they announced the support will continue. Closing Magento Connect the main resource for M1 extensions means one thing, they want us to move to M2. Unfortunately M2 is not as fast as M1 and I don't like the interface. For those who are using desktop computers it really sucks comparing with M1.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a possiblity. As described in [Download the magento connect extensions list](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73109/download-the-magento-connect-extensions-list) you parse some XML files from Magento Connect and download the extensions automatically.

Some working code (for installed extensions) here: [How to keep extensions from Magento Connect up2date without connect-manager?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174281/how-to-keep-extensions-from-magento-connect-up2date-without-connect-manager)

You can also modify it to read http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/packages.xml first (instead of using extension keys stored in DB) and download all extensions you need from MC.

---

#### Edit

Magento Connect is already *dead* and most of the extension are not available at new marketplace.

> 1) There are 3910 paths to extensions in packages.xml file. About 550 extensions are already dead. I checked most of them in Magento Connect using Direct Download extension for Chrome and they won't download. Package information for these 3910 extension still exists and can be download separately. It will help you finding the authors on Internet (GitHub mainly).

Updated extension to download connect modules from magento backend. Complete list of currentlly available extensions here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sreichel/magento-Sr_VersionCheck/master/src/app/code/community/Sr/VersionCheck/data/sr_version_check_setup/data-install-0.0.2.php

For direct download you can use:

```
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/{name}/{version}/{name}-{version}.tgz
```

Comment: I will follow your advice. I have to be fast, September the 15th is coming :)

Comment: For direct downloading I use this extension installed in Chrome: https://github.com/leeroybrun/chrome-magento-connect-ddl. In extension page you get a second button for [Direct Download]. Isn't funny how many nice things Magento Team blows up?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to sv3n information I managed getting all available Free extensions in Magento Connect.

1. There are 3910 paths to extensions in `packages.xml` file. About 550 extensions are already dead. I checked most of them in Magento Connect using Direct Download extension for Chrome and they won't download. Package information for these 3910 extension still exists and can be download separately. It will help you finding the authors on Internet (GitHub mainly).
2. The size of all 2600 extensions available in total is about 600 MB.
3. Over the years the number of free extensions dramatically decreased from 6500 to 2600 as we have today. You still can find extension page for all 3910.
4. Seeing those figures it is clear to me Magento Inc. intention is vanishing Magento 1 in the next year. The decision related to Magento Connect is a correct one, as now Magento Connect provide only information about potential extensions. It is like cutting trees and you still expect fresh air.
5. Marketplace is far away from what we saw years ago in Magento Connect. There are 200 free extensions but they cover only a little part of the issues. For Magento 1 this is a dead end (my personal opinion). A list of Magento 1 developers was a better option. Sad many developers will not update their information in Marketplace.
6. For those who want continuing with Magento 1 starting with September the 15th they will have to spend more time to get what they need. They can ask someone who knows what to do and has good knowledge or using Google for digging thousands of pages. GitHub is a good resource now.

I could switch to Magento 2 but I don't like the backend interface and Magento 2 is lazy on my dedicated server comparing with Magento 1. Many things are good in the new version but speed is a big issue to me.

Starting with September the 15th we close an important chapter in Magento 1. This version is condemned to extinction. If Magento reads this comment please improve speed in the new versions and organize the backend, it is the worst backend comparing with WooCommerce, Prestashop, Open Cart, CS-Cart, X-Cart.