# Unable to find *all* Magento 1 extension screenshots, reviews in Magento 2 Marketplace. Any alternative archive to search/discover/save?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, marketplace

Tried searching Magento 1.x extension screenshots in Magento Connect and was redirected to Magento 2 Marketplace. Tried searching some of the magento 1.x extension screenshots, reviews in the marketplace but was unable to find the extension screenshots. Any solutions?

The old https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ is redirecting to https://marketplace.magento.com/

Anybody else encountered above error?  How to access specific extensions and extension descriptions not available on the new marketplace?

Update 1: By extension, we are referring to both the code and its associated manual, readme, ***screenshots***, **reviews**, descriptions, developer contacts i.e the entire Magento connect archive information.

Update 2: This question is different from the linked question because this is not about updating specific extensions. It is about *all* extensions. It is still unanswered how to retrieve screenshots, reviews, popularity index and that is outside the scope of the other questions mentioned by sv3n.

Comment: You can download and copy the extension manually if you have the source code of the extension. What is the extension?

Comment: There were quite a few extensions and extension descriptions bookmarked, which we would need for every new installation. Maintaining an archive of the M1 magento connect still would be of value for thousands of installations running on M1. So we are looking for ways to replicate the legacy M1 marketplace.

Comment: @sv3n : This question is not just about keeping the extensions updated. But also about, how do you retrieve the descriptions, screenshots, developer contacts of the tens and thousands of extensions, which have now vanished without a trace and without any 18 month advance notice as promised to the community by Jason Woosley, SrVP Magento in the official blogpost. 
https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/ongoing-magento-1-support

The question which you have linked doesn't address how the descriptions, screenshots, developer contacts could be retrieved. It doesn't reference any archive for M1

Comment: Yep, "keeping them up2date" was the initial idea. Now, since Magento Connect is _closed_ you can use it to download all extensions from Magentos backend. Updated answer below to get all information that are available ...

Comment: The information you are referring to seems to be already captured here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sreichel/magento-Sr_VersionCheck/master/src/app/code/community/Sr/VersionCheck/data/sr_version_check_setup/data-install-0.0.2.php which is just the summary information and not the complete information. This does not include $xml->screenshots, or $xml->detailed_descriptions, or $xml->author_email  which served as the readme manuals, extension setup, developer contact info for majority of the extensions. Is that information lost forever or is there an archive for retrieving and storing that?

Comment: You can get most information with the script from below. I guess all things that are not in XML file (like screenshots) are lost ...

Comment: Thanks @sv3n Since, above query of availability of screenshots is still unresolved, please update this question as original and not a duplicate. CC: !Jai !Manoj Deswal !liyakat !Prince Patel

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blogpost:

> We built Marketplace to deliver better experiences for our merchants,
>   partners, and developers. Only select extensions that have been
>   carefully vetted are available, and this helps us ensure that
>   Marketplace represents the best that our community has to offer.

https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/magento-connect-moving-marketplace

I believe the extension you've been looking for which could not be found either did not meet the quality criteria or was not (re)-submitted by their vendor. Contacting the extension vendor(s) might be an option.

Comment: The above blog post confirms the redirection and the abandoning of tens of thousands of M1 installations much before any 18 month notice as announced on the official blog linked to in above article. https://meet-magento.com/breaking-end-of-magento-1-x-support-extended/

The fact that M1 did not meet quality criteria or not resubmitted is not relevant here. The support which includes Magento connect archive is cut off much before any 18 month notice.  Above redirection is a killer blow to the good faith and fair standards the developer and merchant community  expects of the Magento ecosystem.

Comment: Also, how would you contact the developers, when the bookmarks are no longer functioning? The least expected course of action would be to bring back the Magento connect in archive mode with access to contact the developers, extension descriptions,  screenshots, in a read only-mode at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

Two options to find an extension that was not accepted into the new Marketplace.

Note: Who knows how long these will last as they both rely on the "connect20" repository.

**Option 1**

1- Browse Archive.org's archive of Magento Connect using search string "magento-connect" or "magentocommerce"

2- Find the extension's old landing page [takes time and luck, but you may be able to use an bookmarked URL or link]

3- Search source code of landing page for the extension key value.
"extensionKey10" or "extensionKey20"

4- Remove backslashes and paste value into below:

```
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/XXXXX
XXXXX being your extension key
```

5- Paste into freegento downloader: http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

**Option 2**

If you can find the package name and version of the extension somewhere or have an old version of the extension you're looking for, use this URL structure to download direct:

```
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/{PACKAGE_NAME}/{VERSION}/{PACKAGE_NAME}-{VERSION}.tgz
```

Comment: How would you access the M1 extension descriptions of the readme, the screenshots, the developer contact? Also, if you could read the other comments, M1 extension support has been discontinued much before any 18 month notice as announced on the official blog linked to in above article. https://meet-magento.com/breaking-end-of-magento-1-x-support-extended/

Comment: The descriptions are usually in the archive.org waybackmachine. It seems you may be trying to create a repository of the old Magento Connect, which is beyond the scope of your original question. My answer is to your 2 questions in the original post. I understand the discontinuation/deprecation is a huge hassle :(

Comment: No, they are not. They are not archived on archive.org. If you read the above comments, you would realise that the Magento 1 support was assured for 18 months on advance notice. Magento connect Extensions are an integral  part of that assurance made to developers and merchants.  A crowdsourced archive is the only way out, if the new Magento owners, do not reinstate the Magento connect archive. 

An outright breach of faith to the community. It's surprising there's no widespread outrage? Maybe the majority have already moved onto WooCommerce, Shopify, Spree? The end of Magento as we knew it.

Comment: Not sure if you're trolling or what the deal is here. My steps worked for me on several extensions.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve all the extension info and descriptions and screenshot apart from just the summary? I was responding to your statement that these would be archived on archive.org No they are not. Also above method doesn't retrieve the screenshots, the descriptions of all the extensions. This is what the original magento connect archive was for. Is there any comprehensive alternative archive other than the summary list found in the packages.xml      By extension, we are referring to both the code and its associated manual, readme, screenshots, descriptions.

Comment: Option 2 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Free extension to search by extension name, summary and author here:

- [How to keep extensions from Magento Connect up2date without connect-manager?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174281/how-to-keep-extensions-from-magento-connect-up2date-without-connect-manager)

---

**Edit**

To get all information from Magento Connect you can try something like this ...

```
$urls = array();

$client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$client->setUri('http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/packages.xml');

# collect all extension URLs
$request = $client->request();
if ($request->isSuccessful()) {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($request->getBody());
    foreach ($xml->p as $module) {
        $key = (string) $module->n;
        $version = null;
        if ((string) $module->r->s) {
            $version = (string) $module->r->s;
        } elseif ((string) $module->r->b) {
            $version = (string) $module->r->b;
        } elseif ((string) $module->r->a) {
            $version = (string) $module->r->a;
        }
        $urls[$key] = "http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/{$key}/{$version}/package.xml";
    }
}

# get extension information
foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {
    $i++;
    $client->setUri($url);
    $request = $client->request();
    if ($request->isSuccessful()) {
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($request->getBody());
        $version    = (string) $xml->version;
        $stability  = (string) $xml->stability;
        $license    = (string) $xml->license;
        $summary    = (string) $xml->summary;
        $author     = (string) $xml->authors->author[0]->name;
        $date       = (string) $xml->date;
        ....
        var_dump($xml);
    }
}
```

*Example http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/m2epro_ebay_magento/6.3.9/package.xml to see wich information are available (or not, like screenshots ...)*

Comment: One of the links in the question which you have references states "I'm currently building a magento connect extensions search: http://magentoconnect.algolia.com/ but I have a hard time downloading the extensions list + associated metadata." 

That magentoconnect archive on algolia link is not functional and is not public. Is there a working magentoconnect archive you know, which retrieves all the info that magento connect hosted?  Is it possible to retrieve all the extension info and descriptions and screenshot apart from just the summary?

Answer (score -1):

Since Magento 2 launched, marketplace and magento url https://www.magentocommerce.com/ changed to https://magento.com/

You can still download Magento 1.x extensions from [here](https://marketplace.magento.com/extensions.html#q=&idx=m2_cloud_prod_default_products&p=0&fR%5Bext_platform%5D%5B0%5D=Magento%201&hFR%5Bcategories.level0%5D%5B0%5D=Extensions&nR%5Bvisibility_catalog%5D%5B%3D%5D%5B0%5D=1&is_v=1) 
Also if you have connect URL for extensions, you can directly download zip file form [here](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php)

Comment: Tried with above M1 filter, but its not showing all the results which were visible on Magento connect. There were quite a few extensions and extension descriptions bookmarked, which we would need for every new installation. Maintaining an archive of the M1 magento connect still would be of value for thousands of installations running on M1. So we are looking for ways to replicate the legacy M1 marketplace.

Comment: Do you have any bookmark extension link? Which extension you are looking for?

Comment: We have the links and the .tgz for some of them but without the archive descriptions, screenshots - they are useless - for the majority  of developers and merchants in the ecosystem. This is also leading to merchants and developer disputes.  Also, this  redirection is a killer blow to the official magento statement of 18 months advance notice. The same situation is being faced by tens of thousands of developers and merchants. Please refer above comment.

Comment: The new  Magento 2 owners have forced this choice upon the community and do not listen to the feedback from the already dwindling community, We are left with no option than to consider forking 1.9x under a new good faith ecosystem and crowdsourcing the extension descriptions and rallying the Magento 1 developers around the  #RealMagento and the #MagentoConnect archive.